# ¿Como avisar a la aplicación ionic 3 de cambios en la BBDD?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Tengo una aplicación que muestra unos listados y quería informar al usuario si éstos han sido modificados desde la DB. Algo como las notificaciones de firebase o un http listenner, pero no he conseguido nada por ahora.
He estado probando sin éxito con los "ionic native". Necesito alguien que me oriente un poco ;).

- Push: No he conseguido respuesta.
- webServer & httpd: recupero un "plugin_not_installed".

---

```
cordova plugin ls
...
cordova-plugin-webserver 1.0.1 "Webserver for Cordova Apps"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
cordova-plugin-httpd 0.9.3 "CorHttpd"
...
```

Comment: Con este plugin podrás utilizar firebase, aunque tendrás que crearte una cuenta si o si pàra poder utilizar firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente conseguí hacerlo funcionar.
Pero usando:

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver`

de la documentación especifica del plugin ([link](https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver)).
Cuando en la documentación de ionic ([link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-server/)) ponía:

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-webserver`

Alguien podría explicarme la diferencia y/o que problemas podria causarme que ahora en config.xml, package.json y package-lock.json aparezca la forma:

`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-webserver" spec="https://github.com/bykof/cordova-plugin-webserver" />`

cuando antes y en los demás plugins aparece una version numérica?: ...spec="3.0.1"...spec="~2.0.1"...

Adjunto el código por si le pudiese ayudar a alguien:

```ts
constructor(...,private webServer: WebServer) {
this.webServer.onRequest().subscribe(
   data => {
      this.ionicProvider.presentToastOk("This is the request: "+ JSON.stringify(data));
      this.webServer.sendResponse(
         data.requestId,
            {status: 200,
            body: '<html>Hello World</html>',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            }}
          );},
   err=>this.ionicProvider.presentError(err));
}

this.webServer.start()
   .then(res=>this.ionicProvider.presentToastOk('Servidor lanzado? '+res))
   .catch((error: any) => this.ionicProvider.presentError(error));
    });
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
   this.webServer.stop()
     .then(res=>this.ionicProvider.presentToastOk('Servidor cerrado? '+res))
     .catch((error: any) => this.ionicProvider.presentError(error));
}
```

> ionicProvider es una clase propia que simplemente controla la presentación de toasts entre otras cosas.